# PermissionOffer for Non-Registered User

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a use case where I would like to share a realm with a user that has not yet registered with Realm Object Server. The registered user would share a realm with a non-registered user by entering their email address. When the unregistered user registers using the app, they will be granted permission to the realm the first user owns.

How do PermissionOffers work if the user id doesn't yet exist? If the user id is an email address, can the PermissionOffer just hang until a user with the email address is created? What is the suggested workflow for handling something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Permission offers are not bound to user Id. Instead, when you create a permission offer, a random token is generated that the first user sends via any medium (e.g. email/imessage) to the second user. The second user then accepts the offer by consuming the token and receives permissions to the Realm.